# ID of component on Dell G7 7790 laptop motherboard

Tags: identification, components

First time posting, hoping for some help to ID a component on a Dell G7 7790 laptop motherboard.
The laptop would not power on. DC socket is ok and getting feed to the mainboard.
I noticed this component that i'm struggling to ID given some damage to the said component.
It measures (using digital calipers) 2.92mm(L)x 1.57mm(W) x 1mm(H)
There are similar components but none have the same markings.
Any ideas of where to start looking?
Thanks in advance,
Lee.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where is the component located? What is around it, capacitors? inductors? Reference designator (if available)? It looks like an LDO of some sort.

Comment: "5AE" some found [here](https://smd.yooneed.one/code3541.html).  Need to trace surrounding circuitry to determine if it matches any of these listed.

Comment: Components usually don't melt like that without any reason. Please understand that unless whatever problem that caused this part to melt is fixed or removed first ( e.g. USB short circuit, water damage, other component after this short-circuiting), the new part can melt again.

Comment: I received this laptop faulty. There is no sign of liquid damage. The case shows no sign of impact damage. I will add more images to the post to show the location of the component.

Comment: More images added as promised.  Thanks @Lior